# Repeat array rows specified number of times

Tags: arrays, julia

New to julia, so this is probably very easy.

I have an n-by-m array and a vector of length n and want to repeat each row of the array the number of times in the corresponding element of the vector. For example:

```
mat = rand(3,6)
v = vec([2 3 1])
```

The result should be a 6-by-6 array. I tried the `repeat` function but

```
repeat(mat, inner = v)
```

yields a `6×18×1 Array{Float64,3}:` array instead so it takes `v` to be the dimensions along which to repeat the elements. In matlab I would use `repelem(mat, v, 1)` and I hope julia offers something similar. My actual matrix is a lot bigger and I will have to call the function many times, so this operation needs to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been discussed to add a similar thing to Julia Base, but currently it is not implemented yet AFAIK. You can achieve what you want using the `inverse_rle` function from StatsBase.jl:

```
julia> row_idx = inverse_rle(axes(v, 1), v)
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 1
 2
 2
 2
 3
```

and now you can write:

```
mat[row_idx, :]
```

or

```
@view mat[row_idx, :]
```

(the second option creates a view which might be relevant in your use case if you say that your `mat` is large and you need to do such indexing many times - which option is faster will depend on your exact use case).

Comment: This works, thanks! It would be nice to have a direct way of doing this.